# Is there a way to export data from a Twitter search to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: twitter, rss, export, rss-reader

Say you have a [saved search](http://twitter.com/#!/search/cupcakes) on Twitter. Is there a client that will allow me to export the data contained in that search into an Excel spreadsheet?

I am wondering if this will somehow involve the functionality Twitter provides of letting you subscribe to an RSS feed of a search. Is there an RSS reader that would do the exporting I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SocialMention**](http://socialmention.com/) might be what you're looking for. You can export historical Tweets (and other mentins) to a .CSV.

Also, [**Topsy**](http://topsy.com/) works well when it comes to searching for historical Tweets by keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The following article seems promising. It makes use of RSS to achieve what you want:

[Bring Twitter searches into Excel (How to import any Twitter search into an Excel worksheet and update it automatically)](http://office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?a=843)

Comment: Ooo. Looking into this. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it works...

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar - This How-To article, written in April 2009, seems to reference a type of URL string that Twitter no longer uses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog article that explains this and you can export tweets to exce;, pdf, word ,csv etc ..

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/05/activereporting-with-twitter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can export the latest 100 tweets which match your keywords to a spreadsheet here:

http://json-csv.com/export-tweets.aspx 
(this is my website)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free service to [export and download twitter search results](http://www.vicconsult.com/download-twitter-search-results/)
http://www.vicconsult.com/download-twitter-search-results/